# How to call python subprocess using list of different types of parameters

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using Python3 and wants to execute below mention "Testtool" with three different types of arguments as shown below:

```
 'Testtool --noSSLVerify \
    --diskMode=thin \
    --prop:role="Manager" \
    /home/manager \
    data://dir!@172.0.0.0'
```

Above call for Testtool is working fine on the command line, Now I want to invoke the same command using the python sub process.

I am using List and adding all of the arguments and calling the subprocess.call() method as shown below.

```
list = list()
list.append("noSSLVerify")
list.append("diskMode=thin")
list.append("prop:role=\"Manager\"")
list.append("/home/manager")
list.append("data://dir!@172.0.0.0")


subprocess.call(["Testtool"] +list )
```

How can i pass three different types of parameters in the above sub process call to make it running?

Three different types of params are mention below. 
E.g.

1. `noSSLverify` as it doesn't have value but just the param name only;
2. `--diskMode = thin` - this comes with param name and its value as well;
3. `data://dir!@172.0.0.0` - this param doesn't have value and contains special characters and does not start with "--".

Comment: I'm not convinced this is an exact duplicate. You are missing the dashes off the args. Otherwise looks reasonable.

Comment: All of these arguments are strings; and indeed, a list of strings is the only data type you can pass to a subprocess. You should obviously not be omitting the leading dashes in front of options; the quotes are what you should be dropping. None of the other characters here are special to either the shell or to Python.

Comment: And what about the special characters like "data://dir!@172.0.0.0". It should go as it is?

Comment: (Updated the previous comment to address specifically that, apparently while you were typing yours.)

Comment: For fun, experiment in the shell with `printf '>>%s<<\n' --diskMode="thin" --prop:role="Manager" data://dir!@172.0..0.0 $HOME "$HOME" `$HOME`` and explore the differences in the output.